# Making a textured object a particle

Tags: particles

Okay, I'm kind of new to blender particle systems but my question is,  How do I create a textured model and make it  part of a particle swarm?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well, I think I found what I was looking for. I'll post the link for others who are curious. Just wasn't looking up the right keywords.

The answer is by using Boids in blender. Boids allow you to create a model and then apply it as a particle to create a "swarm" effect. The link shows how to create a school of fish that move in a manner like particles by using Boids in Blender.

https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-animated-fish-swarm-in-blender-using-particles-part-1--cg-13929

Comment: It is encouraged to answer your own questions, but please do so in a descriptive manner. Link only answers are discouraged, it is not searchable and if the link goes down your answer becomes empty and invalid for future users. Please add a short description of the solution and some example images along with the corresponding link.